# Prove $f(x) =0$ for all $x \in [a, b]$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

If $f:[a,b] \rightarrow R$ be continuous , let $f(x) =0$ when $x$ is rational. Prove $f(x) =0$ for all $x$ that is an element of $[a,b]$.

Thanks for the help I can't seem to find the f[a,b] notation in my notes and it is throwing me off.

Comment: If you're asking about the notation $f([a,b])$, it is simply shorthand for the set $\{f(x):x\in[a,b]\}$. It's the image of the set $[a,b]$ under $f$.

Comment: $f : [a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ means that $f$ is a function which maps reals in the interval $[a,b]$ to reals.

Comment: @CameronWilliams thanks for that! Now it's a matter of solving it. That's the main part.

Comment: @KajHansen thanks for the kind words. Any help on actually solving it. I've been playing around with a delta epsilon proof and I'm getting stuck and getting lost in my work

Comment: You should include details on what you are having trouble with, it could help people answer the question in a way that is helpful to you.

Answer (score 3):

Go back to the definition of continuity.  If such a function is continuous, then for any given $\varepsilon > 0$ and $x \in [a, b]$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $|x-y| < \delta \implies |f(x) - f(y)|< \varepsilon$.

So what problems arise if there is an $x \in [a, b] \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ such that $f(x) \neq 0$?  Well, we can always find a $y \in \mathbb{Q}$ that is as close to $x$ as we'd like (in math jargon, $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$).  As a hint, let $\varepsilon$ be the value of $f(x)$.

Can you fill in the details?

Comment: I'm sure I'll get it in a minute or so. I'll comment back if I get stuck again. Thanks!

Comment: Yup officially lost in my proof. Any other hints? I understand that y is an element of the rationales and it has to be close to x but now I'm lost.

Comment: So we have chosen a $\varepsilon > 0$ and $x$ such that $f(x) \neq 0$, and we are trying to show that no $\delta$ exists.   To do this, suppose we *did* have a $\delta$, and remember we can always find a $y \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $y$ is within $\delta$ distance of $x$.  What goes wrong?  Unfortunately it's hard to say much more without giving it away, so I'll let you think about it for a little longer.  (Math is about struggling with the concepts, after all)

Comment: Yea sorry I have nothing. |x-delta, x+delta| < y? I'm officially lost sorry for keeping you up with this.

Comment: Yeah, so suppose $y \in [x-\delta, x+\delta]$ is rational.  Now try computing the difference of the function values at $x$ and $y$.

Comment: So y = 0 which is less than delta and therefore a contradiction?

Comment: @ChrisMillett it is possible that $0\notin [x-\delta,x+\delta]$ for specific choices of $x$ and $\delta$, so you cannot choose $y=0$.  But as Kaj has mentioned, you can choose $y$ to have a specific **Q**ualitative property, which should tell you something about $f(y)$.

Comment: @JMoravitz so then f(y) can not =0 and therefore f(y) > 0 <delta?

Comment: @ChrisMillett Last comment for me, then I'm heading to bed.  Although we cannot gaurantee that $y$ can equal zero, according to our definition of $f$, $f$ of any rational number *is* equal to zero.  $x$ and $y$ are in the **D**omain and we compare them to $\delta$ in our epsilon-delta proofs.  Meanwhile $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ are in our rang**e** and we compare to $\epsilon$ in our proofs.  We do *not* under **any** circumstances try to compare $f(y)$ to $\delta$.  I strongly recommend looking over definitions of continuity you used when first learning calculus.